# Getting NaN for seemingly no reason

Tags: loops, while-loop, nan

I am writing a program to estimate sin(x) using its Taylor polynomial expansion. I am calculating the first 100 terms of the expansion. It goes like this:

```
sin(x) = x - x^3/3! + x^5/5! - ...
```

and so on. My program compiles but I get `NaN` for any input of `x`. The int fac is the factorial of whatever n is at the time, which is determined by the for-loop nested in the while-loop. I had thought the `NaN` was caused by the fac being 0, since the sum involves dividing by fac. I don't see how this could be the issue.

```
public class deleteThis {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double x=Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
        double sum=0.0;
        int n=1;
        double neg1=1;
        int fac=1;
        while (n<100) {
            fac=1;
                for (int i=1; i<n; i++) {
                    fac=fac*i;
                }
            sum+=neg1*Math.pow(x,n)/fac;
            n+=2;
            neg1=-neg1;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

$ javac deleteThis.java

$ java deleteThis 1.0

NaN

$ java deleteThis 100

NaN

Comment: Can you include the command you are using to run this?

Comment: Yeah @AndrewEisenberg